# 3d function with different contours per pairs of variables (sketch available)

Tags: geometry, functions

I am searching for a function of 3 variables $y = f(x_1; x_2; x_3)$ which would satisfy the following property:

Per each pair of variables it would give a different contour based on the following graph:

[pairs of axes in 3d graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZcqh.png)

**Remark:** it does not have to be strict linearity in case of $x_1$ and $x_3$ but close to linearity and similarly for $x_1$ and $x_2$ it does not have to be triangular but close to triangular.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The most important part is the graph. I am searching for 3d function whose 3d graph  would result in the outlined illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question cannot receive a satisfying answer.

Indeed you can fullfill 2 constraints but not three.

I am going to show why with the help of the Geogebra graphical representation here :

[image]

The reason for that is understandable by thinking in terms of "backprojection". The backprojection of

- the segment of line is a plane.
- the hyperbola is a kind of cylindrical surface.

These two surfaces intersect along a curve (in red) but you cannot constrain any more the third projection to be what you desire it to be.

Said otherwise if you consider the third desired projection (with the right angle), the corresponding third backprojected surface would intersect the two other backprojected surfaces into a single point... not a curve.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think that if we relaxed the constraints a little bit, meaning that both pairs $\{ x_1; x_2 \}$ and $\{ x_1; x_3 \}$ would be curved more like $x_2$ and $x_3$, it could be satisfied?

Comment: Maybe. A seemingly thorough methodology is to start from an existing curve like the red one and trying, as you say it, to relax the constraints. But your condition to have a right angle projection, oriented as you indicate it, looks hard to to fulfill at the same time as the other conditions.

Comment: To answer differently : yes, one can surely increase the "bend" of one the curves in order it becomes closer to a 90° angle. But this "almost right" angle will not be turned in the right direction, isn't it ?